# PHP DOMDocument AppendXML returns empty (special characters)

Tags: php, dom, special-characters, domdocument

I've got a view.phtml file that gets loaded into a DOMDocument using AppendXML. However, when this view.phtml contains text loaded from the DB that contains special characters like '&', it crashes on the AppendXML call:

> DOMNode::appendChild(): Document Fragment is empty in ...

where the document fragment loads the HTML of view.phtml:

```
    $newDocFrag = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    $newDocFrag->appendXML($html);
```

but apparently returns an empty fragment.

This seems to be the case when I load text that contains the '&' symbol from the database. However, when I directly put it inside of the view.phtml file it does work properly, without any errors.

Does anyone have any idea why this is causing a problem and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `&` is a special character in XML. Can you provide a sample string and what the goal is? I'd guess you should use an HTML parser... or correct the input so it uses entities.

Comment: @user3783243 Ah I suspected so. My goal is to have a layoutformer inside of my MVC framework that allows for adding templates to specific elements of the page by defining these inside of a layout.xml file.